# DevOps predefined variables query

Tags: azure-devops

CODE:
echo "(Build.Buildnumber) : $(Build.Buildnumber)"
buildNumbertest= "Build.Buildnumber"
echo "buildNumbertest : $buildNumbertest"
echo "(buildNumbertest) : $($buildNumbertest)"
[Enter feedback here]

OUTPUT:
2020-05-28T20:50:05.0263387Z (Build.Buildnumber) : 2020.515.94
2020-05-28T20:50:05.0266228Z /home/vsts/work/_temp/eece4524-81e3-42d6-b7ca-a6d208853b8b.sh: line 12: Build.Buildnumber: command not found
2020-05-28T20:50:05.0268635Z buildNumbertest :
2020-05-28T20:50:05.0269958Z (buildNumbertest) :

How do I get to access value after doing string operations and passing it as $($VARIABLE_NAME)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use variables in your script dynamically:

1. [Set variables in scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts):

> @echo ##vso[task.setvariable variable=sauce]crushed tomatoes

2 [Get variable value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-pipeline):

> Batch script: %VARIABLE_NAME%
>
> PowerShell script: $env:VARIABLE_NAME
>
> Bash script: $VARIABLE_NAME